# Can we extend the validity of presigned URL for snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I have requirement where in I need to share the URL generated from snowflake to end user so that the user can download the images.

The issue here is when I use the presigned URL, the validity I get for the URL is 1 hour max. If it try to increase it, it gives me the below error.

> GET_PRESIGNED_URL expiry in seconds for AWS role is invalid. Must be between 0 and 3,600.

If I try to use the BuILD_SCOPE_URL, from snowsight I am able to download the files but when I use it in a new browser tab, it reports the below error.

> {
> "code" : "391902",
> "message" : "Unsupported Accept header text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 is specified. Result set format must be JSON."
> }

How can I generate the URL's from Snowflake and share it to end user?

Comment: Does the end user have access to Snowflake or would they only have the url?

Comment: If the end user is a snowflake user, you can use the build scope URL, however when the same is passed in the new browser tab, you are likely to encounter the error as there is no credentials passed.

You can make use of curl to retrieve the results by passing in the snowflake authentication as header.

curl  <build_scope_url> -H "X-Snowflake-Authorization-Token-Type: KEYPAIR_JWT" -H "Authorization: Bearer <jwt_token>" -L 

You can use either of the methods mentioned here. (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/authenticating)

Comment: If the user is not a snowflake user, then presigned URL is the best option to generate the URL and share it to the end user. The maximum validity is 1 hour and we do not recommend to increase it further as there are security considerations that needs to taken care of.